# Foreign Key violation - not sure why

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have the following two tables with a foreign key on `status_id`:

```
mysql> describe usr_cookbook;
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| user_id   | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| recipe_id | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| status_id | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| added_ts  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+

mysql> describe usr_cookbook_status;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| status_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name      | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There's two rows in `usr_cookbook_status`:

```
mysql> select * from usr_cookbook_status;
+-----------+-----------+
| status_id | name      |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | Try Soon  |
|         2 | Favorites |
+-----------+-----------+
```

So I should be good to insert into usr_cookbook right?

```
mysql> insert into usr_cookbook (user_id, recipe_id, status_id) values (3, 5, 1);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails (`tomato`.`usr_cookbook`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cookbook_status` FOREIGN KEY 
(`status_id`)
REFERENCES `usr_cookbook_status` (`status_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE
NO ACTION)
```

Why the constraint violation?  The `status_id` I'm using (1) exists in the parent table.  I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing here...

Comment: please show us your DDL rather than the "describe" commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I looked at the DDL per Brian's suggestion the problem immediately became clear: The `usr_cookbook_status` table was using MyISAM engine.  I switched it to InnoDB and everything works now.

Comment: And that's called rubber-ducking. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @jcolebrand: I've never heard that term before, had to look it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: And more than once I've typed out a complete question in stackoverflow and then go "oh."

Comment: You should visit http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general we do it quite often in there, as well http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general or better would be ;) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/database-administrators